# Php - Fastest method to loop through associative array keys

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I only need to loop through the keys of the associative array.

Is this syntax the quickest way to do it?

`foreach (arr as $key => $value) {`

I'm not going to use `$value` at all.

All I need is `$key`...

Comment: arra_walk and array_walk recursive?

Comment: @Thamilan that is not the quickest way, it needs more lines to do the same as `foreach (arr as $key => $value) .....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run a static analysis with a tool like like [PHP Mess Detector](https://phpmd.org/) against that code it will report you have an unused variable.

If all you want are the keys then use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the keys and then loop through them.

```
foreach (array_keys($arr) as $key) {
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is, there is other ways but are more "complex". Your way is the fastest and easiest one.